# Can b2 Visa be revoked if applying for child shortly after receiving?

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

My mother in law applied for a b2 Visa from jordan to help come and assist my wife after she gives birth in June. We filed DS-160 a few a weeks ago and she got approve and Visa issued. She has a 12 year old son that we also wanted to come with her and thought about doing an application for him. Today she asked someone at aimmigration office in Jordan and they told her that there is a high chance of her Visa getting revoked  if she applies for her son and that she should have done it with her application. How can someone's Visa be revoke based on someone else application?

Thank you

Also the child's father passed away about 3 years ago

Comment: It could depend on whether the child remaining behind in Jordan was portrayed as a tie to home and a compelling reason to return in your MIL’s application. Applying to have her son accompany her in a subsequent application rather than at the outset could be seen as immigrant intent.

Comment: @Traveller SOunds like an answer to me.

Comment: Would the fact that she has 4 daughters help? The son is the youngest and the daughters all work full time and not home most of the day.  Why would they not just deny him rather then revoke the MIL Visa?

Comment: @Thaer Why did they not apply together in the first place?

Comment: We was going to do but a friend told us she has a better chance of applying on her own then going back and add the child later. I regret taking that advice now

Comment: Yes it is very true. Many people’s visa are being revoked in Venezuela (and other countries) after they take their children in for visas. I will post the news reports shortly. It’s a recent phenomenon under Trump although there may be underlying reasons.

Comment: My suggestion for you is let the child apply however your mother in law should not be the adult who takes him for the interview. If your father in law does not have a visa, he should take him instead. That way her visa is not at risk.

Comment: https://www.nbcnews.com/news/latino/amid-crisis-venezuelans-say-u-s-revoking-tourism-visas-n876166 _In last April, they went to the American Embassy in Caracas with his 87-year-old grandmother so she could be interviewed as part of her visa application. **At the end of the appointment, his grandmother's visa was denied and his was revoked**_. This is not only happening in Venezuela, it’s happened in my country Ghana, Haiti etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B1/B2 visa applicants need to overcome the US assumption of immigrant intent. If your mother-in-law portrayed ties to home that included her 12 year old son remaining behind during her visit in her application, it would be unwise to present a different picture subsequent to obtaining her visa by applying for a visa for her son to accompany her. It could well look like an attempt to hide intentions to overstay in the US; having adult daughters who work stay behind isn’t such a strong tie as a dependent child.

You will never know if she would have been given the visa if she had applied with her son in the first place. IMHO it would be safer to follow the advice of the Immigration office in Jordan and proceed with the visit as described in the application. You should be aware that even having a visa does not guarantee entry https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html